# Linear Mapping in a Graph

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear mapping and $G$ the set of points limited by the triangle $abc$. Find $T$ and represent the image of the graph $G$ through $T$.
[image]

I have not idea how to find the matrix $T$, and less how to represent $G$ through $T$, could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using linear combinations, observe that:
\begin{align*}
T(b) &= T(-5,2) \\
&= T(\tfrac{1}{2}(-10,3) + \tfrac{-1}{6}(0,-3)) \\
&= T(\tfrac{1}{2}a - \tfrac{1}{6}c) \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}T(a) - \tfrac{1}{6}T(c) &\text{by the linearity of $T$} \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}(1,3) - \tfrac{1}{6}(9,3) \\
&= (-1, 1)
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you explain me, what did you do, please?

Comment: I can't understand the part $\tfrac{-1}{6}(0,-3)$. Why $\tfrac{-1}{6}$

Comment: @LuisArmando we are two dimensional vector space and the vectors $(-10,3)$ and $(0,-3)$ are linearly independent and hence is a basis. so third vertex $(-5,2)$ can be written as  linear combination of these basis vectors.

Comment: @GA316, thanks I understand now :)
I still don't know how to find the matrix $T$, could you help me with that?

Comment: Try expressing both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ as linear combinations of $a$ and $c$, and using the same trick as above. Then $T$ is the matrix whose columns are given by $T(1,0)$ and $T(0,1)$.

Comment: @Adriano, I have a doubt, let's say that $T(1,0) = (-1,-3/5)$ and $T(0,1) = (-3,-1)$. Could be Matrix $T=$ 
$$-1 , -3/5$$
$$-3 , -1$$

Or $T=$
$$-1 , -3/5$$
$$-3/5 , -1$$

Could you help me with this?

Comment: You have to concatenate them as column vectors:
$$T = [\color{red}{T(1,0)} ~~~ \color{blue}{T(0,1)}] = \begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{-1} & \color{blue}{-3} \\
\color{red}{-3/5} & \color{blue}{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$